# How can I bind bootstrap date time picker values to an angular model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I bind bootstrap date time picker values to  an angular model

My model looks like this:

```
$scope.Video = {
  StartTime: '',
```

In my controller my date function looks like this:

```
    $(function() {
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
    });
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class='input-group date'  id='datetimepicker1'  >
      <input ng-model="Video.StartTime" type='text' class="form-control" id="inputStartTime" />
     <span class="input-group-addon"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
</div>
```

When a date is selected form my  date picker the  input field is populated however my angular model Video.StartTime isn’t assigned the value.

I have tried adding the following to the date picker function which didn’t work:
      $scope.Video.StartTime = $("#datetimepicker1").value;

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `datepicker` directive in `angular-ui` project

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

## http://plnkr.co/edit/5SYeKPI0tBAbTgkXnXik?p=preview

Comment: I don't want to change my Ui..I want to use what I have